# How can a grep for a specific field and less the entire line

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I would like to know how can a grep for a specific field on each line of a file. I don't want to grep the entire line for a pattern.

e.g.

```
33 >> sender1 >> recipient2 >> subject vvv
33 >> sender2 >> recipient2 >> subject aaa
22 >> sender1 >> recipient3 >> subject ccc
22 >> sender1 >> recipient3 >> subject xxx
```

- 1) How can I grep only in recipient field ?
- 2) How can I grep only in sender and recipient field?

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"grep" on recipient only:

```
awk -F'>>' '$3~/yourPattern/' file
```

on recipient and sender:

```
awk -F'>>' '$3~/yourPattern/||$2~/yourPattern/' file
```

Comment: Did you mean for the opening `/`s to be after the `~`: like `$3~/yourPattern/` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `awk` instead of `grep`, for searching in sender filed

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /sender/ { print }' filename.txt
```

For searching in sender and recipient filed

```
$ awk '$3 ~ /sender2/ || $5 ~ /recipient2/ { print }' filename.txt
```

Fields are separated by white space. You can add your custom delimiter by `awk -F">>" '$3 ~ /sender/ { print }' filename.txt`  You can use conditions in `AND,OR` by replacing `|| for OR`  and `&& for AND` logic.

Comment: note that `awk '$3 ~ /sender/'` is the same as `awk '$3 ~ /sender/ {print}'`, since `{print $0}` (or `{print}`) is the default action that `awk` performs when a condition evaluates to True.

Answer (score 0):

A variation on what has been posted already:

```
awk -F' *>> *' '$3=="recipient2"'
```

This sets the Field Separator to something more useful, as it includes the spaces. And now `recipient20` will not be matched. You could prevent these false matches by including anchors like `^` and "$`, or`>`and`\<``, but testing for equality is often easier.

The following has tests for the second field, in the first variant the line is printed if any of the two match, in the second, when both conditions are met:

```
awk -F' *>> *' '$3=="recipient2" || $2=="sender1"'
awk -F' *>> *' '$3=="recipient2" && $2=="sender1"'
```

Answer (score 0):

awk is sweet, but the following might be more intuitive for a non awk user.

recipient field:

`cut -d'>' -f5 filename | grep searchString`

sender and recipient field:

`cut -d'>' -f3,5 filename | grep searchString`

But you do lose the rest of the line.